# Sending Values to VB.NET application in client PC From local server using PHP

Tags: php, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have three client PCs and one local server (actually a pc- Using windows 7 Ultimate on it).

In the server pc I have XAMPP installed and I am running an application developed using PHP  on it. There I have the following PHP variables:

```
 $id='something';
 $value='something';
```

In client PCs I have a software developed using VB.NET installed (and no XAMMP) and there I have the following VB function

```
Public Function Hello(ByVal test As String,ByVal test As String) As Boolean 
     //some code    
End Function
```

Sorry, If the VB.NET code above is wrong, I have zero knowledge in VB.NET(my friend will develop the VB.NEt part)

Now, My question is if there is any way to send the values of the above PHP variables to the VB function in any of the client PCs, using PHP?  Lets say the IP address of my client PCs are: 
`192.168.30.1`,`192.168.30.2`,`192.168.30.3` . If there is would you please kindly tell me how to do it or do you know any article on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Send to the client PCs?  No.  Even if PHP could do this, how would the server know when to send the values to the client?  What would trigger that?  How would it even know the application is running on the client?

You could have the client app call the server inside the function to retrieve the values.  The easiest way would be to set up a RESTful endpoint, but you could use something like SOAP as well.  All depends how complicated you want to get.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer was really helpful. I was actually planning to create button to trigger that, however as you said the easiest way would be set up a RESTful endpoint and you're right. :) But I have a question to ask if you don't mind, If I create a restful endpoint then how the VB.NET app will know when to communicate with the restful endpoint. It would be immensely helpful if you could at least tell me the logic, then I will ask my friend to work on it. I have very little knowledge in programming and I am still trying to learn PHP, so I am sorry if I sound stupid. :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use Windows URI Scheme.
It's the same method used in μTorrent's Magnet Links.

Register your application to it:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx

Then you can use application arguments to catch the data.
Don't forget to make your application single-instance.